# How to access file in Spring Boot Cloud Config from another branch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

When connecting to a git-configured spring boot cloud config server, how do you reference a different branch?

Currently I can access a subfolder's data by doing curling `localhost:4001/myservicename/default`.  Where the `myservicename` is a subdirectory, with my application.properties includes the subfolder: `spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths=myservicename`
The current default-label is: `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main`

Comment: localhost:4001/myservicename/default/branch

Answer (score 0):

Like @spencergibb answered you can access the branch using next link:

```
localhost:4001/myservicename/default/branch
```

To explain this link

```
<server ip/fqdn>:<port>/<service name>/<profile name>/<branch name>
```

A little more info: To have different profile versions you need to create files like this

```
app-name-<profile>.properties
```

Now to access different branch from spring code you need to add next line to **application.properties** file

```
spring.cloud.config.label=<branch
```